# Firebase Auth Network Error from event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the following error when trying to login. The email address exists on Firebase Auth and I'm able to login, but the error weirdly only happens when `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. Those two lines are listed with the comment "(UNCOMMENT AND ISSUE GOES AWAY)".

**Possible Issues:**

Is there something else I am missing in my  code or did I make a mistake somewhere else?

**Error:**

> Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

**Login.js**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Container, Form, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

// Imports: Redux Actions
import { loginRequest } from '../../../src/redux/actions/authActions';

// Page: Admin Login
const Login = () => {

  // React Hooks: State
  const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');

  // React Hooks: Redux
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // React Hooks: Bootstrap
  const [ validated, setValidated ] = useState(false);

  // React Hooks: React Router DOM
  let history = useHistory();

  // Login To Account
  const loginToAccount = (event) => {
    // Form Validation Target
    const form = event.currentTarget;

    // Check Form Validity
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      // Cancels Event
      event.preventDefault();

      // Prevents Bubbling Of Event To Parent Elements
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
      // Validate Form
      setValidated(true);

      // Check If Fields Are Empty
      if (
        email !== ''
        && password !== ''
        && email !== null
        && password !== null
        && email !== undefined
        && password !== undefined
      ) {
        // Credentials
        const credentials = {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        };

        // Redux: Login Request
        dispatch(loginRequest(credentials, history));

        // // Cancels Event (UNCOMMENT AND ISSUE GOES AWAY)
        // event.preventDefault();

        // // Prevents Bubbling Of Event To Parent Elements (UNCOMMENT AND ISSUE GOES AWAY)
        // event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <NavigationBar /> */}

      <Container id="login-container">
        <div id="login-inner-container">
          <div id="login-logo-container">
            <p id="login-title">Login</p>
          </div>

          <Form validated={validated} onSubmit={(event) => loginToAccount(event)}>
            <Form.Group controlId="login-email">
              <Form.Label className="form-field-title">Email</Form.Label>

              <Form.Control
                type={'email'}
                placeholder={'Email'}
                pattern={'[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$'}
                onChange={(event) => setEmail((event.target.value).toLowerCase())}
                value={email}
                maxLength={50}
                required
              />

              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Invalid email</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId="login-password">
              <Form.Label className="form-field-title">Password</Form.Label>

              <Form.Control
                type={'password'}
                placeholder={'Password'}
                onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                value={password}
                maxLength={40}
                required
              />

              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Required</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Button
              variant="primary"
              type="submit"
              id="login-button"
              onClick={(event) => loginToAccount(event)}
            >Login</Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
};

// Exports
export default Login;
```

Comment: By default the form submit will trigger a reload if you do not use event.preventDefault. this might lead to the API error

Comment: Wouldn't I only want `preventDefault()` to happen if the form is invalid? If the if/else statement, should the `preventDefault()` only happen when `form.checkValidity() === false`?

Comment: Not really, preventDefault is usually used when you want to handle the custom functionality on submit and not the browser default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering your `` function as the submit handler for a form:

```
<Form validated={validated} onSubmit={(event) => loginToAccount(event)}>
```

When a HTML form is submitted, its default behavior is to send the data to the server as a request that navigates away from the current page. The logic here is that the server handles the request, and send a response to the client that it then renders. That's pretty much how the web worked 20+ years ago, hence it being the default behavior for HTML forms.

So with the commented out `preventDefault`, your code starts signing in to Firebase and then immediately navigates away (most likely just reloading the same page). This interrupts the sign-in, which is why you see the error message.

By calling `event.preventDefault()` you indicate that you want to prevent the default behavior (the submitting of the form to the server), since your code is handling that itself (by calling `loginRequest`).

Calling `stopPropagation` stops the browser from giving parent HTML elements the chance to act on the event. It typically shouldn't be needed to prevent the form submission, but depends a bit on the HTML that is generated.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation of things!